# Discord Bot Only Showing 3 Servers to Add in Authorization

Tags: bots, discord

I've tried to add my Discord Bot to another server, but only 3 servers show up in the authorization. I'm signed in and everything, and I have Administrator for my bot. I've tried everything and nothing seems to work. Please help.

[Discord Bot Authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDsMz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add a bot to a server if you have administrator rights within that server

If you do have permission and even then can't get the bot to join, try having either another account or someone else to add him.